# Translator using container locale parameter instead of the session locale

Tags: internationalization, symfony

I have defined my routing using the special `_locale` parameter. When a route is matched by the router, the locale is correctly set in my user session and I can see the correct locale being used in the profiler.

```
$this->get('session')->getLocale(); // Return the correct locale
```

The problem is that the i18n translator is always using the default locale defined in my parameters.yml file instead of using the locale set in the session.

Is there something i'm missing ? Do I have to manually pass the session locale to the translator ?

I'm using Symfony 2.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: [Translations configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration), "The locale used in translations is the one stored in the user session.". If it's not the case for you, I guess you changed something in your configuration?

By the way, the locale will be stored in the request and not in the session anymore in 2.1: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/74bc699b270122b70b1de6ece47c726f5df8bd41